# Keras: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'fit'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Was working on my AI course projects, and suddenly found `keras.models.Sequential.fit` disappeared.

Tested on codes which has already been run successfully, also failed, raising the same error.

Grabbed some random keras demo code on Google, same result.

Running this random keras demo code from Google:

```py
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
import numpy as np
 
x = data = np.linspace(1,2,200)
y = x*4 + np.random.randn(*x.shape) * 0.3


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse', metrics=['mse'])

weights = model.layers[0].get_weights()
w_init = weights[0][0][0]
b_init = weights[1][0]
# print('Linear regression model is initialized with weights w: %.2f, b: %.2f' % (w_init, b_init)) 


model.fit(x,y, batch_size=1, epochs=30, shuffle=False)

weights = model.layers[0].get_weights()
w_final = weights[0][0][0]
b_final = weights[1][0]
# print('Linear regression model is trained to have weight w: %.2f, b: %.2f' % (w_final, b_final))

predict = model.predict(data)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MY_CWD/main.py", line 21, in <module>
    model.fit(x,y, batch_size=1, epochs=30, shuffle=False)
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'fit'
```

Environment:

python==3.10.6, keras==2.12.0, tensorflow==2.12.0

OS:

Ubuntu22.04.2

Answer (score 0):

Running this locally seemed to not produce any errors which makes me think that something has gone wrong with the import of `Sequential` in your script.

One thing that may help get to the bottom of the issue is to use `inspect` which is in the python standard library (you won't need to pip install anything new).

```py
import keras
# ... (your code as before)
# ...

# Add the snippet below before you call model.fit(...):
# -----------
import inspect
print(inspect.getmodule(model))
# -----------
model.fit(x,y, batch_size=1, epochs=30, shuffle=False)

# ...
```

The above addition should print out some info just before the error occurs. Something like:

```
<module 'keras.engine.sequential' from '/your/python/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py'>
```

It's at this point that we can verify where `Sequential` is actually being imported from. I'm assuming that it won't be the same as the above given that `.fit` is missing.

Once you've got that info, maybe we can then get to the bottom of the issue.

Comment: It may also be interesting to call `dir()` on the model object to see what methods are available.